# Parse with PHP - on Godaddy Hosting

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, svg

I’m looking to parse various files with PHP, such as CSS, XML, and SVG. Using .htaccess I was able to get my localhost to do so, but unable to get that same code or any other variations to work online.

Using the .htaccess file I should be able to do this, and was able to successfully do so on my localhost; but can not get it to work on GoDaddy Linux hosting.

I've tried a few variations in the .htaccess, here's one example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.xml$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And also tried:

```
 Options +ExecCGI
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .xml .css .svg
    AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .xml .css .svg
```

both sitemap.xml and stylesheet.css contain PHP to set header, and dynamically change/generate content.

Comment: Hosting companies usually limit what kind of functionality you can add to the server, I think it would be best to contact your hosting company's tech support!

Comment: @Aziz yeah, tried that. Even time I use their chat system they tell me tech support isn't available that this time (time-zone), and apparently they don't do email or ticket support anymore.